# oracle query find employee with maximum period of service

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have these tables with the following columns :

```
 Employee24( EMPLOYEEID, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME,DATEOFJOINING );
```

I want to find the employee who has maximum period of service.

```
    Select * from employee24 where Max(DATEOFJOINING);
```

Comment: How could  `Max(DATEOFJOINING)` equal  maximum period of service ? You should perhaps rename that column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a subquery:

```
Select * from employee24 
where DATEOFJOINING = ( 
   SELECT Max(DATEOFJOINING)
   FROM employee24
);
```